# Run docker build - Cant not found docker file

Tags: docker

This is how I try to make use of Github Actions in relation to the project being built in Docker. I have look on this site here: [How do I specify the dockerfile location in my github action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61874021/how-do-i-specify-the-dockerfile-location-in-my-github-action)

That which I would like out of it. It is that it makes use of the docker File that makes in my project.

I have built like this in relation to my files:

API

- Docker

Service

Data

Test

However, it's the case that my Docker is in the API section.

I have tried this:

```
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build ./API/ --file Dockerfile --tag my-image-name:$(date +%s)
```

and i have try

```
docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag my-image-name:$(date +%s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the "./" in front of dockerfile name:

docker build . --file ./Dockerfile --tag my-image-name:$(date +%s)

**UPDATE:**

After looking at Docker.com documents, I found the solution using Docker Compose. Just use:

**docker-compose up**